# Getting error while pushing model of object using useState

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-hooks

while pushing a model of object ,getting issue ,having attached my code for reference.

initialise the array

```
  const [carModel, setCarModel] = useState([]);
```

my carData is a array of having some data form API,then used a loop to iterate the carData array and tried pushing in the carModel using useState

```
if (hookData.CarData != null) {
      for (let i = 0; i < hookData.CarData.length; i++) {
        carModel.push({
          modelPrice:  hookData.CarData[i].ModelPrice,
          modelName:  hookData.CarData[i].ModelName,
          point: hookData.CarData[i].Point,
          favStatus: 0,
          digit: hookData.CarData[i].Digit,
          askColor: "white",
          symbol: hookData.CarData[i].symbol,
          localName: hookData.CarData[i].LocalName,
        });
        setCarModel((carModel) => [
          ...carModel,
         carModel[i],
        ]);
      }
    }
  }
```

I am a beginner in react native,in this case not getting the required result.what the correct way to use useState in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Setting state inside loops is not ideal. Typically you would need to create a new array and push objects to that array, then you can set the new array.

Example:

```js
 const addMultitpleCarModels = () => {
    let newCarModel = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < hookData.CarData.length; i++) {
      newCarModel.push({
        modelPrice:  hookData.CarData[i].ModelPrice,
        modelName:  hookData.CarData[i].ModelName,
      });
    }
    setCarModel((prevCarModel) => {
      return [
        ...prevCarModel,
        ...newCarModel
      ]
    })
  }
```

Ref: [Getting error while pushing model of object using useState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74035558/getting-error-while-pushing-model-of-object-using-usestate/74035645?noredirect=1#comment130722683_74035645)

You can set local name like this:

```
const setCarLocalName = (modelName: string, localName: string) => {
      setCarModel((prevCarModel: any) => {
        return prevCarModel.map((model: any) => {
          if (model.modelName === modelName) {
            return {
              ...model,
              localName
            }
          }
          return model;
        })
      })
    }
```

Comment: thanks @Stephen ,Just a small question.if I have the change the value specific carModel like carModel[2].Name = 'newName'.How we can achieve this using useState

Comment: @ManishKumar Just edited my post, showing how to set an object key inside an array of objects